# Поставить запятые в предложении

Tags: пунктуация

Где нужно поставить запятые?

Что это за человек и какое нужно с ним обращение?

Comment: Стася вроде правильно поняла, что Ваше предложение вопросительное, так что нужен вопросительный знак в конце, а иначе это вообще не предложение, а только какая-то придаточная часть.))

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

В сложносочинённых предложениях запятая между частями не ставится, если они  представляют собой побудительные, вопросительные или восклицательные предложения; объединяющей здесь оказывается интонация: *Где будет собрание и кто его председатель?* — общая вопросительная интонация; Как тихо вокруг и как чисто звездное небо! — общая восклицательная интонация (по В. В. Лопатину). В Вашем примере запятая не нужна: "*Что это за человек и какое нужно с ним обращение?*".